# Beamer TOC gives wrong section number

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

Because my Beamer files are large, I split then into separate `.tex` files and start a new part with e.g.

```
\addtocounter{section}{3}
```

This works in that the first section in this `.tex` file correctly appears as Section 4 (correct also in footlines and headers).

However, in the TOC on the first page of the PDF, the first section appears as section 1, not as section 4! Same with the sections that follow: they appear as 2 and 3 in TOC, not as 5 and 6.

Is there a separate counter for the TOC? If so, how can I manipulte it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Note that you don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post. Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: I really hate doing that for my own answer, but since my response below seems to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers.

Answer (score 1):

Write the following somewhere in your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\advance\beamer@tocsectionnumber by 3
\makeatother
```

This might have other undesired results but this steps the number in toc. 
 Note: beamer does many things different form latex2e, this is one example. If you are interested in further investigations on this take a look into a "normal" toc file an beamer's toc file.

Comment: It works, thanks. No undesired side effects so far!